# How to create a Class Based Views search bar on Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm making a search bar in Django using Class-Based Views on my Views.py. When I try to get the value submitted in the input it's not showing the query name and if I don't submit anything is NOT giving me an error. Also what is the way to get the post showed by the world searched? Thanks for all. My code is:

Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model): # Post core
    title = models.CharField(max_length=299)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,default=ANONYMOUS_USER_ID, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    desc = models.TextField()
    text = RichTextField(blank = True, null = True )
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null = True, blank = True, unique=True)

    class Meta: # Order post by date
        ordering = ['-date',]

    def __str__(self): # Display title 
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self): # #TODO da cambiare
        return reverse("listpost")
```

Views.py:

```
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "admin/search.html"
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        q = request.GET.get('q', '')
        self.results = Post.objects.filter(text__icontains=q, desc__icontains = q, title__icontains = q)
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Urls.py:

```
    path('dashboard/listpost/search/', SearchView.as_view(), name="search")
```

ListPost.html:

```
{% extends "admin/layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
    <title>Post List</title>
{% endblock title %} 
{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="GET">
<input type="text" placeholder="Cerca" name="search"> <button>Cerca</button>
</form>
<div class="postlist">
    <div class="cards"> <!-- Card Container -->
        {% for post in object_list %}
            <div class="card"> <!-- Single Card  -->
                {% if post.image %}
                    <img src="{{post.image.url}}" alt="">
                {% endif %}
                <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
                <p>
                    <a href="">{{ post.category }}</a>
                    <a href="">{{ post.author }}</a>
                    <data class="data"> {{ post.date|date:'d-m-Y'  }} </data>
                </p>
                <p class="desc-list">{{ post.desc|truncatewords:10 }}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'editpost' post.slug %}" class="edit-link">edit</a>
                <a href="{% url 'delatepost' post.slug %}" class="delate-link">delate</a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

Search.html

```
{% extends "admin/layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
    <title>Search</title>
{% endblock title %} 
{% block content %}

{% if query %}

{{Query}}

{% else %}
<p>Nope</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are trying to display the variable *query*, *Query* (two different variables since the template language is case sensitive).

Your do not pass any of those two variables in the template context.
I don't see any *query* nor *Query* variable in your view.

It seems that your want to show the *results* variable, so I will assume this.
Your need to send the *results* from your queryset in the template results.
The [*get_context_data*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) method ContextMixin (one of the TemplateView derived classes) is useful for this.

```
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "admin/search.html"
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        q = request.GET.get('q', '')
        self.results = Post.objects.filter(text__icontains=q, desc__icontains = q, title__icontains = q)
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Add context to the template"""
        return super().get_context_data(results=results, **kwargs)
```

And in your template:

```
{% extends "admin/layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
    <title>Search</title>
{% endblock title %} 
{% block content %}

{% if results.exists %}
  {% for result in results %}
    {{ result }}
  {% endfor %}

{% else %}
  <p>Nope</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```